# Xcode: ld: 275 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, reactjs, compiler-errors, cocoapods

I am trying to archive my project so I can submit it to the app store.  It builds with no errors or warnings but when I archive it I get:

ld: 275 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

If anyone has any ideas please let me know!  I tried setting the GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS from YES to NO 
as well as removing the -ObjC from other linking flags.

Also everything imported is .h there are not .m's

CocoaPod file

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
target “” do
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'RCTMapboxGL', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-mapbox-gl/ios'
pod 'React', :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'React/RCTGeolocation', :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'React/RCTImage', :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'React/RCTNetwork', :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'React/RCTText', :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'React/RCTWebSocket', :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'AWSCore'
pod 'AWSAutoScaling'
pod 'AWSCloudWatch'
pod 'AWSDynamoDB'
pod 'AWSEC2'
pod 'AWSElasticLoadBalancing'
pod 'AWSKinesis'
pod 'AWSLambda'
pod 'AWSMachineLearning'
pod 'AWSMobileAnalytics'
pod 'AWSS3'
pod 'AWSSES'
pod 'AWSSimpleDB'
pod 'AWSSNS'
pod 'AWSSQS'
pod 'AWSCognito'
pod 'AWSCognitoIdentityProvider'
end
```

[image: Linked Libraries and Frameworks]

Comment: The errors say that you're linking libReact.a and libRCTWebSocket.a and that both of those contain the same class: RCTWebSocketModule.

Comment: yesss!!!!! thats it they were contained in the reactlib.a I just removed the extra links and its worked.  Thank you. Please answer the question and i'll give you the check!

Comment: You may find what you look for here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46678210/988941

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments:

The errors say that you're linking libReact.a and libRCTWebSocket.a and that both of those contain the same class: RCTWebSocketModule.

Comment: So this worked to archive it, but now when I to to run it react is telling me native modules cannot be null.  Any ideas?  If I remove them from being linked it gets rid of the warning but then my app wont run :/  I am removing them from linked frameworks / libraries

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "native modules cannot be null".  Can you update your question with the actual error message?  (Is it possible you have different link settings for different configurations?)

Comment: So I am using react-native when I try to archive I get the error above.  To fix that archive error I deleted the extras in the Linked Frameworks and Libraries.  This fixed my archive error however now these modules aren't linked correctly anymore thus react-native thinks the native modules are null?  So I don't think I can remove them from there.  I'm not sure where else they would be getting linked. Any ideas? Would something like rnpm link them? Then the xcode would try to relink them?

Comment: Do you build libRCTWebSocket.a or is that a 3rd-party thing?  If you build it, it seems like the answer would be to not put RCTWebSocketModule into it and pick that up from libReact instead.

Comment: Currently in xcode I am building it but I believe cocoapods might be building it as well.Im still learning cocoapods. I'm going to put my pods file above in 1 sec

Comment: This was the correct answer I just had to find out how to correctly remove which was being linked.  I had to do a little work on my pod file and rework how my frameworks and libraries were being linked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the podfile, try removing the lines

```
pod 'React/RCTGeolocation', :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'React/RCTImage', :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'React/RCTNetwork', :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'React/RCTText', :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'React/RCTWebSocket', :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native'
```

Just keep the core "React" line i.e.

```
pod 'React', :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native'
```

and run "pod install" again.

It looks like RCTWebsocket is already included in your project, so installing from the podfile again causes an error.