# Archive ReactNative got duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, react-native

I tried to archive an IOS project with ReactNative. Got this error:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_RCTWebSocketModule._methodQueue in:
    /Users/xuleyuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SWCRN-ewdfdwvyvsgtsjbhztxszcugwdph/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SWCRN/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libReact.a(RCTWebSocketModule.o)
    /Users/xuleyuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SWCRN-ewdfdwvyvsgtsjbhztxszcugwdph/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SWCRN/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTWebSocket.a(RCTWebSocketModule.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_RCTWebSocketModule._sockets in:
    /Users/xuleyuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SWCRN-ewdfdwvyvsgtsjbhztxszcugwdph/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SWCRN/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libReact.a(RCTWebSocketModule.o)
    /Users/xuleyuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SWCRN-ewdfdwvyvsgtsjbhztxszcugwdph/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SWCRN/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTWebSocket.a(RCTWebSocketModule.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTWebSocketModule in:
    /Users/xuleyuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SWCRN-ewdfdwvyvsgtsjbhztxszcugwdph/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SWCRN/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libReact.a(RCTWebSocketModule.o)
    /Users/xuleyuan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SWCRN-ewdfdwvyvsgtsjbhztxszcugwdph/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SWCRN/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTWebSocket.a(RCTWebSocketModule.o)
ld: 441 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But I can run it with simulator rightly.What I have done:

1. delete duplicate targets in pod and main project
2. search compile source but find nothing duplicate
3. turn off  No Common Block of all the targets
4. In project/Pods I found a Headers folder which contains two folders named public and private with duplicate file .Should I delete one of them?

Comment: You may find what you look for here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46678210/988941

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. I solved this problem!

Just remove all about React in PodFile (Only React) and everything become pretty