# 79 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am working in React Native project and I am trying to build the project and I am facing this error now

```
/Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-cdhqlijyeqlscheswseaiojrllyn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/`**TcpSockets**`/libTcpSockets.a(GCDAsyncSocket.o)
ld: 79 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

I had like **144** `duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64` and my error was something like that.

`/Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-cdhqlijyeqlscheswseaiojrllyn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/`**react-native-udp/**`../..`

and when I uninstall `react-native-udp` the duplicate symbols decreased from 144 to 79

and I tried to delete the `TcpSockets`  but it gets created with the build or `install pod`

I don't have much knowledge in Xcode so Any clues what's the problem or maybe solution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [duplicate symbols for architecture x86\_64 ios React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214603/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-ios-react-native)

Comment: @tomerpacific  the libraries folder is empty I auto-linked all libraries that I used

I just have error in the `Pods/Products/libPods-ProjectName-ProjectNameTest.a` (in red), and I don't what does that mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was not CocoaAsyncSocket but there was GCDAsyncSocket.
Solution:

1. Go to xcode
2. into project navigator, click on Pods folder
3. then select TcpSockets in targets
4. Go to Build Phases > Compile sources
5. Here remove reference to CocoaAsyncSocket
   Or run this command line:

   rm -rf node_modules/react-native-tcp/ios/CocoaAsyncSocket

More detail: https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-tcp-socket/issues/61#issuecomment-653881488

Comment: i run your command line but still got 79 duplicate, example: ***dvceggxlntuarreqgqsecyhizzua/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/TcpSockets/libTcpSockets.a(GCDAsyncSocket.o)*** please help

Comment: In this case, we can remove manually by following the path of source code

Answer (score 1):

Here:
Check your package.json if it has

- react-native-tcp and react-native-tcp-socket

If yes (mine did) run:

- npm uninstall react-native-tcp
- cd ios
- pod install
- react-native start