# iOS ReactNative React dependencies problem

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

We are trying to build ios react native application that uses static libs and cocoapods dependencies. All dependencies need React. Problem that we are facing is that when we include static libs we need to include React as static lib too so that it can build. And when we include cocoapods dependencies they also need React. So we icluded React in cocoapods too. But that results in duplicate symbols error. So is there a way to include React only once and point Cocoapods to that dependency or the other way around, install React via Cocoapods and point my static libs to use React from Cocoapods. Or is there some third way to do this. We have wasted days on this, any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This question should provide help for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021796/react-native-xcode-project-product-archive-fails-with-duplicate-symbols-for-arch

Comment: We have tried suggested solution and it still returns 1300 duplicate symbols. It looks like removing the target or @objC flag does not work any more

Comment: Do you own the static libs? If so the easiest thing (by far) to avoid all this non-sense would be to create private cocoapods for yourself. Each pod could have react as a dependency during their development, and when cocoapods pulls it all together, only 1 version of react gets pulled down. Passing all of this manual work to the dependency manger should be your goal. Personally i'd stay the hell away from react-native in the first place, but thas me

Comment: What about editing the end of your podfile to add the code for removing react? Can you try adding that, deleting your pods folder and run pod install? Also did you make sure to clean your project again just in case?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up wrapping all static libs that were not managed by cocoapods in our own private cocoapods like @Simon McLoughlin suggested and it worked like a charm. So if anyone stumbles on a similar problem, this is by far simplest solution, trying to mix cocoapods with static libs is never ending story. Thx Simon.